# How to put 5 div in 1 main div horizontally and the margin between 5 div is same

Tags: html, css

Currently, I create a system webpage that need to put 5 div in 1 main div horizontally.
But, i want the between 5 div margin is equal to each other at fix the main div. Below is my current page looks like:

[image]

From above image, I want to arrange both 5 div is fix to the main div, which is example, the "SUSTAINABILITY" is locate at the red line. Below is my current code:

```
<div class="prolist">

<div class="col2 left paddingLR">
    <div class="item2 aligncenter">
    <div class="iteminner bgP">
        <div class="itemcircle"><a href="/financial-summary-p-815/"><img src="/App_ClientFile/7ff8cb3f-fbf6-42e7-81da-6db6a0ab2ef4/Assets/ir/financial.jpg" alt="" /></a></div></div>
    <h5>FINANCIAL Information</h5><a href="/financial-summary-p-815/">read more..</a></div></div>
<div class="col2 left paddingLR">
    <div class="item2 aligncenter">
    <div class="iteminner bgB">
        <div class="itemcircle"><a href="/annual-report-p-817/"><img src="/App_ClientFile/7ff8cb3f-fbf6-42e7-81da-6db6a0ab2ef4/Assets/img-financial-report.jpg" /></a></div></div>
    <h5>ANNUAL<br />
        REPORT</h5><a href="/annual-report-p-817/">read more..</a></div></div>
<div class="col2 left paddingLR">
    <div class="item2 aligncenter">
    <div class="iteminner bgO">
        <div class="itemcircle"><a href="/corporate-calendar-p-823/"><img src="/App_ClientFile/7ff8cb3f-fbf6-42e7-81da-6db6a0ab2ef4/Assets/ir/calendar.jpg" alt="" /></a></div></div>
    <h5>Corporate Calendar</h5><a href="/corporate-calendar-p-823/">read more..</a></div></div>
<div class="col2 left paddingLR">
    <div class="item2 aligncenter">
    <div class="iteminner bgG">
        <div class="itemcircle"><img src="/App_ClientFile/7ff8cb3f-fbf6-42e7-81da-6db6a0ab2ef4/Assets/ir/IR circle picture.JPG" alt="" /></div></div>
    <h5>CORPORATE PRESENTATION</h5><a target="_blank" href="/App_ClientFile/7ff8cb3f-fbf6-42e7-81da-6db6a0ab2ef4/Assets/IR Presentation/TG Website_English_240420.pdf"> English</a> /<a target="_blank" href="/App_ClientFile/7ff8cb3f-fbf6-42e7-81da-6db6a0ab2ef4/Assets/IR Presentation/TG Website_Chinese_240420.pdf"> Chinese</a><br />
    </div></div>

<div class="col2 left paddingLR">
    <div class="item2 aligncenter">
    <div class="iteminner bgB">
        <div class="itemcircle"><img src="/App_ClientFile/7ff8cb3f-fbf6-42e7-81da-6db6a0ab2ef4/Assets/ir/sustain_icon.jpg" alt="" /></div></div><br />

    <h5>SUSTAINABILITY</h5><a target="_blank" href="/sustainability/"> read more..</a></div></div>
</div>
```

and I want the position like this: (just a sample)

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't completely understand the outcome you are seeking.  Could you provide a visual mockup of how it _should_ look?

Comment: Note: the `<br>` and `<img>`  tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Comment: use flexbox in your css. here is the reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex for that.

```
.prolist {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-between;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: why does width have quotes around it? im curious

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i change to phone view, the div will exceed the view

Comment: @PeterDavidson You've not mentioned any where what you need when it comes to mobile view, do you want them to position one below another with a width of 100%

Comment: @PLZHELP used to write quotes, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

It would have been nice if you had given the css used for this page. So here is a quick fix, I hope it works:

```
.prolist {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   flex-direction: row;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Presently if you have given margins to create space between each element , you can remove that, as this code will give you equal spaces betweem them. If this doesn't work, please upload the css you have used for this page.

Comment: I always add `flex-direction: row` to clear up any confusion that could arise if people are not familiar with flexbox.

Comment: Yes , that would be perfect

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i change to phone view, the div will exceed the view

Comment: @Peter Davidson that is a seperate question.

Comment: @PeterDavidson Check if giving flex-wrap: wrap to the .prolist solves your problem on phone view.